# Why My Android Application Classes Occupy so Much Space

Tags: android, apk

I just build a package of my android app and after analyzing its content I realize that classes2.dex which pretty much is the content of my java code and classes is about 3.4 Megs. next res directory 700 K which is understandable, I have a few png images. But why is the size of classes2.dex so big. I have 15 Classes in my application. That's quite a bit of code, but I don't think should be 3.4MB. My question is why could this be and how can I optimize the size of my application, I'd like to make it smaller. Thanks
here's a screenshot
http://pctechtips.org/apps/androidapp.png

Answer (score 0):

To reduce your apk size you should use code shrinking

From the documentation:

> you must enable code shrinking. During the build process, first [Proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) emoves unused code but leaves unused resources. Then Gradle removes the unused resources.